# For loop in C breaks early for no obvious reason - possibly related to a function pointer (call back)

Tags: python, c, for-loop, callback, ctypes

I am experimenting with a DLL written in C and callback functions written in Python. My DLL contains the following definition and routine:

```
typedef int16_t (*conveyor_belt)(int16_t index);

int16_t __stdcall DEMODLL sum_elements_from_callback(
    int16_t len,
    conveyor_belt get_data
    )
{
    int16_t sum = 0;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        sum += get_data(i);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

I call the above from a Python script using `ctypes`:

```
import ctypes

DATA = [1, 6, 8, 4, 9, 7, 4, 2, 5, 2]

conveyor_belt = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_int16, ctypes.c_int16)

@conveyor_belt
def get_data(index):
    print((index, DATA[index]))
    return DATA[index]

dll = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary('demo_dll.dll')
sum_elements_from_callback = dll.sum_elements_from_callback
sum_elements_from_callback.argtypes = (ctypes.c_int16, conveyor_belt)
sum_elements_from_callback.restype = ctypes.c_int16

test_sum = sum_elements_from_callback(len(DATA), get_data)
print(('sum', 48, test_sum))
```

The output I get looks like this (most of the time):

```
(0, 1)
(1, 6)
(2, 8)
(3, 4)
(4, 9)
(5, 7)
(6, 4)
(7, 2)
('sum', 48, 41)
```

From what I can tell, the for loop just does not iterate over all 10 elements of DATA as I would expect it to do ... It usually "breaks" after 8 elements, sometimes even only after 5 or 6. I can confirm that the length of DATA is correctly passed into the DLL routine. I am puzzled.

---

Just in case this is a compiler (flag) issue, here is an excerpt from my makefile:

```
CC      = i686-w64-mingw32-gcc
CFLAGS  = -Wall -Wl,-add-stdcall-alias -shared -std=c99
LDFLAGS = -lm
```

I am working with mingw (32 bit) on top of 64 bit Linux:

```
user@box:~> i686-w64-mingw32-gcc --version
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc (GCC) 7.2.0
user@box:~> uname -s -r -p
Linux 4.4.114-42-default x86_64
```

For running the DLL and the Python script, I am using an official 32 bit release build of CPython 3.5.3 for Windows on top of 32 bit Wine:

```
user@box:~> wine --version
wine-2.18
```

It's a robust combination which I have been using intensively for a while now.

---

Using the call back in the C code makes a difference. The following code will stop after about 5 to 8 iterations (without error):

```
int16_t sum = 0;
int16_t sum_index = 0;
int16_t i;
for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    sum_index += i;
    sum += get_data(i);
}
```

The following code will iterate to the end as I do expect it. It just does not call the call back function:

```
int16_t sum = 0;
int16_t sum_index = 0;
int16_t i;
for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    sum_index += i;
    // sum += get_data(i);
}
```

Comment: have you simply printed the value returned by "len(DATA)" ?

Comment: @Tom's Yep, it's 10.

Comment: Have you tried printing `len` in the C function?

Comment: then I'm as puzzled as you. Can you try debuging step by step and/or adding printf debug in the C dll (like knowing value of len and result of get_data)

Comment: Why is `conveyor_belt` a `WINFUNCTYPE` taking two parameters?

Comment: @JeremyP Yep ... I have filled my C function with plenty of printf statements ... all it did was make the loop break even earlier (sometimes, non-deterministic).

Comment: @quamrana That's a Python/ctypes thing. The first parameter actually is the return type of the function prototype, the second one is the (first/only) parameter type.

Comment: @Tom's I have filled this thing up with printf statements, see comment(s) above. I guess I'll have to run this thing through a debugger.

Comment: It seem you have missed an argument in "ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE" part.
The first argument must be the return type (which you do correctly) and the other must be the argument type. But there, you only supplied "c_int16" (corresponding to argument "len"). The fact that the function pointer is missing is do on purpose ?

Comment: @Tom's Hmm maybe I am misunderstanding this. The `ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE` part only describes the interface of the call back function: `get_data`. It has one argument and one return value.

Comment: No, it's me : I'm not used to python and particulary on this kind of stuff. You seem doing it rigth, so we get back on "debugging" the whole thing.

Comment: I can't reproduce this.

Comment: @n.m.Thanks a lot for trying. I added more info about my test environment at the bottom of my question. Maybe it helps.

Comment: This is not supposed to happen so I would suggest firing up a debugger. Possibly over a debug build of Python too.

Comment: You've got a calling convention mismatch. This may give you a mismatched stack pointer, and could potentially cause your local variables, such as i and len, to be overwritten.
You should either use CFUNCTYPE or add __stdcall to your function pointer type declaration.

Comment: @ThFabba Yep, this works. Thanks a lot, you saved the day :) Feel free to post this as an answer: `typedef int16_t __stdcall (*conveyor_belt)(int16_t index);` is all it required.

Comment: Worth noting that this fails in 32-bit Python due to the mismatched calling convention.  64-bit Python doesn't fail because there is only one calling convention and __stdcall/__cdecl are ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conveyor_belt function is not defined in the same way between C and Python.

```
typedef int16_t (*conveyor_belt)(int16_t index);
```

This declares your function pointer type to use the cdecl calling convention (unless overridden by special compiler flags).

```
conveyor_belt = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_int16, ctypes.c_int16)
```

Whereas this declares your Python function to use stdcall calling convention.

Calling the function with the wrong calling convention will offset your stack pointer a little bit every time. Depending on the stack layout your compiler generated, this may end up overwriting local variables or parameters (i.e. i or len to cause your loop to break).

You should either switch from WINFUNCTYPE to CFUNCTYPE to indicate cdecl, or change the typedef to add __stdcall:

```
typedef int16_t (__stdcall *conveyor_belt)(int16_t index);
```

(Note that the calling convention belongs inside the parentheses but before the asterisk. Some compilers accept it in other places, but MSVC will not.)